# Unit testing InstallScript

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installscript, installscript-msi

I've got a handful of functions in my **InstallScript** that are good candidates for unit tests. My project is a **InstallScript MSI project**. I found an article about how to unit test Custom Actions with custom ICEs, but the code I want to unit test isn't in a Custom Action, it is in the UI sequence.

Is there a way to unit test this kind of InstallScript code?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the `SprintfMsiLog()` InstallScript function.  It will write to the MSI log file, and so you can troubleshoot what's happening just as if it were an MSI standard action.

I hope I'm understanding what you mean by "unit test".

Comment: That isn't exactly what I was looking for. I would like to execute InstallScript functions the same way I can execute Java functions with JUnit or the same way I can execute C# functions with NUnit. 

However, writing intermediate output to the log file is a good idea.